# How to negate the regex in HTML page?

Tags: regex, html, javascript

I have a requirement in which we need to restrict the user from entering any of the below value:

000000001 to 000000009 ...  999999990 to 999999999 (unacceptable values)
123123123 (unacceptable value)
123456780 to 123456789 (unacceptable value)

I came up with the below regex :

`([0-9])\1{7}([0-9]){1} | 12345678([0-9]){1} | (123){3,9}`

This regex can validate if the user has entered incorrect value.

But I am not able to negate the regex.
 I tried using (?! ) but still it is not performing the negation.

Any help?

Comment: Does it need to be a regex? You tagged this with [javascript], any reason the validation cannot be done via JS (where you could use multiple regexes and other logic)?

Comment: as per the existing code .logic they want us to do on HTML page using regex just like it is being done for other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
^(?!(\d)\1{7}\d|12345678\d|(?:123){3})\d{9}$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/E0WkjH/1)

Comment: Great..!! It's working like a charm. Can you please help me to understand what went wrong with the regex (?!(([0-9])\1{7}([0-9]){1}|12345678([0-9]){1}|(123){3,9}))
which I tried before?

Comment: @sfdc07: You have a negative lookahead alone in your regex, it doesn't match anything, lookarrounds are zero-length assertions, that is the more important thing, a regex must have a pattern outside lookaround to match something. You can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/3DpCPF/1/) an explanation of your regex. Also `(123){3,9}` means: match `123` between 3  and 9 times, so `123123123` upto `123123123123123123123123123`. You haven't anchored the regex `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end. `{1}` is useless. `[0-9]` can be shortened to `\d`.